# How to get the BSON from a ReactiveMongo BSONDocument in scala?

Tags: scala, bson, reactivemongo

I have a ReactiveMongo BSONDocument but I want to write it to a file - I know there's the BSON format (http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) and I want to write it according to those specs, but the problem is that I can't find any method call to do this. I've been able to convert it to an array of Bytes, but the problem begins when I convert to a string, UTF8 format by default.

However the BSON specs require a 32 bit number in the beginning. Is there a library that can do this for me? If not, how can I add string representing a 32 bit number and UTF8 string together without losing the encoding for either or both?

Here's what I've got in Scala:

```
import reactivemongo.bson.buffer.ArrayBSONBuffer

val doc = BSONDocument("data" -> overall)
val buffer = new ArrayBSONBuffer() 
BSONDocument.write(doc, buffer)
val bytes = buffer.array

val str = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF8"))
```

For reference, I know in Ruby, we can do something like this, but how do I do the same thing with ReactiveMongo?

```
bson_data = BSON.serialize({data: arr}).to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.reactivemongo/reactivemongo-bson-api_2.12/0.20.3/reactivemongo/api/bson/BSONDocument$.html), you can use `BSONDocument.pretty(myDoc)`.

Note that you are using the [deprecated/being removed BSON API](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/bison.html).